# Using custom module in MailHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, helper

I have a custom module I would like to access in my mail helper, but i can't figure out how to include it.

My custom module `lib/workday.rb`:

```
module Workday
  def next_workday(date = Date.today)
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

That i try to use in my MailHelper:

```
module MailHelper
  include Workday

  def next_workday(date = Date.today)
    Workday.next_workday(date)
  end
  ...
end
```

When trying to use the helper i get this:

```
undefined method `next_workday' for Workday:Module
/www/xxx/app/helpers/mail_helper.rb:4:in `next_workday'
```

When manually including the module in the console it works fine directly and through the helper:

```
> include Workday
=> Object
> Workday.next_workday
=> Fri, 04 Jan 2013 
> helpers.next_workday
=> Fri, 04 Jan 2013
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a `Module` the methods will be accessible as instance methods. If you try to access the `next_workday` method directly through the module, the method must be defined as a "class method" (with `self.`).

Your `MailHelper` should work if you use:

```
module MailHelper
  include Workday
end
```

There is no need to define the `next_workday` method in `MailHelper` since it just delegates to `Workday#next_workday` anyways. If you include your `MailHelper` into a class you can then access the method with `next_workday`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfect. I can see that i didn't get the concept of including a module. The code looks much better now.